# How to delete a record from database through AJAX using php and also when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

How to delete a record from database through AJAX using php and also when link is clicked it returns to same page and new list is updated when a link is clicked and id passes through this link ? I am new to AJAX and php

Comment: follow this url very helpfull
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917833/delete-record-in-a-table-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: I have seen the question and its an answers,But it's not helping out.

Comment: post your code what are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a class="delete_data" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
ajax
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete_data").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'delete.php',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) { // Sucess
        } else { // Error }
      }
   });
 });
});
delete.php
$id = $_POST['delete_id'];
$query = "delete from TABLE NAME where ID = $id";
```

Comment: Thanks! what does class in your link refer to  <a class="delete_data" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>

Comment: it is deleting the record however I have to refresh the page to view the new list

Answer (score 1):

@TOORPIZZZ You can add this to remove the row from the display without refreshing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete_data").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   var parent = $(this).parent();
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'delete.php',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) { parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                parent.remove();
        } else { // Error }
      }
   });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have } in a comment by //Error. It took a while until I discovered this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete_data").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   var parent = $(this).parent();
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'delete.php',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) { parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                parent.remove();
        } else { // Error }        <----------------
      }
   });
 });
});
```